# How to write a lot of nested 'for' loops (Recursively)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
word = "word"

# Splitting word into its characters
newword = []
for char in word:
    newword.append(char)

print newword


#getting all permutations
test= []
for i in newword:
    for j in newword:
        if i != j:
            for k in newword:
                if j != k and i!= k:
                    for l in newword:
                        if i != l and j != l and k != l:
                            test.append(i+j+k+l)

print test 
print type(test)
print len(test)
```

These 4 nested loops work nicely for 'word' because it has exactly 4 letters in it. 
If I wanted as many 'for' loops as there are letters in any given word, how can I do this?
Any nice tricks?

Comment: inspectorG4dget's solution is the correct one. If, however, you for some reason wanted to roll your own permutation generator instead, you would want to find a way to attack the problem _recursively_, rather than by nesting a gorillion loops.

Comment: @senshin ah, so the word i'm looking for is recursively! I am aware that there are modules out there that can get me all the permutations in a single LOC but I wanted to do it myself

Comment: The Wikipedia section on [algorithms to generate permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations) might be worth taking a look at if you want some ideas.

Comment: Side note: you can replace `newword` with `word`, as `for` directly iterates over the characters of a string. Furthermore, if you insist on using a list of characters, `newword = list(word)` is simpler (it works in the same way as the `for` loop, by definition, as `list()` iterates over the word's character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general recursive problem you are trying to solve. `itertools` already contains functions for practically all implementations you could possible need. However, if you want something to learn about, this is one way of doing it. I will permute a list of numbers. In this case, Ill find permutations for:

```
[0,1,2, ... ,N-1]
```

Note that once you have the permutations for the above, you can simply use these as the indices for permuting anything. So what is the general way of doing this?

Let us first look at the result for a specific case. For the case of say `[0,1,2,3]`. The result we are looking for is the list of lists:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 3, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 3], [2, 0, 3, 1], [2, 1, 0, 3],
 [2, 1, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1, 2], [3, 0, 2, 1],
 [3, 1, 0, 2], [3, 1, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

The idea is to write a function that takes a single list of lists, and *increment* it. Consider the simple function:

```
def permNums(inp, N=4):
    newInp = []
    for i in inp:
        for j in range(N):
            if j not in i: newInp.append( i+[j] )
    return newInp
```

Now execute this funciton with an empty list of lists ...

```
In [22]: permNums([[]])
Out[22]: [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

What happens when you run it again with its output?

```
In [23]: permNums(_)
Out[23]:
[[0, 1],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 3],
 [1, 0],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 0],
 [2, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [3, 0],
 [3, 1],
 [3, 2]]
```

and repeat it again?

```
In [24]: permNums(_)
Out[24]:
[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 2],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 3],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 3, 0],
 [1, 3, 2],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [2, 0, 3],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [2, 1, 3],
 [2, 3, 0],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [3, 0, 1],
 [3, 0, 2],
 [3, 1, 0],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [3, 2, 0],
 [3, 2, 1]]
```

Do it another time, and you will get the result you want.

Now you can consider the simple implementation:

```
result = [[]]
for i in range(N): result = permNums(_)
```

This *will* solve your problem (you just need to map the indices to your string, and join the result). However, this is not classical recursion. For recursion, there are two additional steps you need the perform.

1. Call the function within itself
2. Figure out when this calling-itself business is going to stop ...

Calling the function within itself is simple. Just replace

```
return newInp
```

with

```
return permNums(newInp, N)
```

This step should not be surprising because this is exactly what you did manually on the iPython console. However, you will need to stop at some point. In this specific case, the stopping criterion should be simple. If the number of elements in one of the inner lists `== N`, then stop.

So the modified program has two simple additions:

```
def permNums(inp, N=4):

    if len(inp[0]) == N: return inp # stopping criterion

    newInp = []
    for i in inp:
        for j in range(N):
            if j not in i: newInp.append( i+[j] )

    return permNums(newInp, N) # keep calling itself 

print permNums([[]])
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: @ssm You start your answer with the list [0,1,2, ... ,N], Why haven't you used [1,2,3,...,N] or, better, [0,1,2,...,N-1] (i.e., the value of range(len(word)))? On all other accounts, a very good answer tuned on the OP real needs. Ciao from

Comment: ssm it's weird how my first comment has disappeared. anyway I modified your code a little and got it to take a string as an input and give all the word permutations. thanks again

Comment: I just discovered that my modified code has a flaw, if the word is for e.g., 'well', the 2 l's mess with the  "if j not in i:" line. So I guess I have to stick to using integers and then mapping it to alphabets later on lol!

Comment: Yes that is why I had refrained from using the characters for checking for equality. I should have mentioned that somewhere. Also the reason I didnt go the `for j in word:` and realted changes which would have messed everything up.

Answer (score 8):

```
In [10]: import itertools

In [11]: word = "word"

In [12]: test = [''.join(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(word)]

In [13]: test
Out[13]: 
['word',
 'wodr',
 'wrod',
 'wrdo',
 'wdor',
 'wdro',
 'owrd',
 'owdr',
 'orwd',
 'ordw',
 'odwr',
 'odrw',
 'rwod',
 'rwdo',
 'rowd',
 'rodw',
 'rdwo',
 'rdow',
 'dwor',
 'dwro',
 'dowr',
 'dorw',
 'drwo',
 'drow']
```

Comment: Thanks Inspector, however isnt this a bit of a free ride?  Is there anyway I can get the same effect without using  permutations() ?

Comment: Sure. You can write a lot of nested `for` loops.

Comment: @IanAuld: I suspect this is homework, and OP can't use built-ins as they would be "free rides". Either that, or OP is trying to learn some graph traversal algorithms